# Que signifie « normale » dans « École Normale Supérieure » ?

Tags: sens, éducation

Que signifie « normale » dans « École Normale Supérieure » ?

En anglais on utilise souvent « *normalized* ». Est-ce que l'intention est d'utiliser un sens pareil ?

Answer (score 7):

Non, pas du tout. *Une école normale* est une école où les profs sont formés.

On utilise "normal" de la même façon en anglais : [Normal school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_school)

Comment: Jusqu'un 1991 on utilisait aussi "[école normale (primaire)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89cole_normale_primaire)" pour l'endroit où étaient formés les instituteurs.

Comment: C'est le nom donné lors de sa fondation, en 1794, à la première école destinée à préparer à l'enseignement des étudiants sélectionnés par concours, et qui est aujourd'hui appelée "École normale supérieure". Le but était de former des maîtres pour des écoles normales secondaires réparties sur l’ensemble du territoire et permettre ainsi d’assurer un enseignement de base "conforme à la norme", homogène pour tous.

Answer (score 7):

Les premières « [écoles normales](http://www.memoireonline.com/08/09/2613/m_Contribution-des-Ecoles-Normales-Primaires-au-processus-de-lEducation-Pour-Tous15.html) » datent de la fin du 17<sup>e</sup> siècle. Il s'agit d'écoles organisées par l'Église catholique, fondées par [Jean-Baptiste de La Salle](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Baptiste_de_La_Salle), mais à destination de laïcs, par opposition aux seuls enseignements organisés à l'époque qui étaient destinés aux futurs prêtres. Le [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/normal) indique pour ce sens dans sa section étymologie

> l'adjectif a le sens de « qui sert de modèle » d'après le sens du latin *norma* (v. norme) « ligne de conduite, prescription ».

Il s'agissait alors de répandre une instruction avec une forte composante religieuse ; les enseignants étaient des religieux, et les élèves étaient des laïcs destinés à enseigner à leur tour à des laïcs.

Sous la Révolution, en 1795, le terme « [école normale](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89cole_normale_(R%C3%A9volution_fran%C3%A7aise)) » a été repris dans ce sens, mais il ne s'agissait alors plus de répandre des valeurs religieuses mais des connaissances, avec de fortes composantes scientifiques et techniques.

Avec ces deux précédents historiques, le terme « école normale » signifie une école qui forme des enseignants. Il s'est spécialisé en France dans deux institutions :

- les [écoles normales primaires](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89cole_normale_primaire), fondées sous l'Empire (début du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle) et qui prennent leur forme moderne lors de la laïcisation de la société à la fin du XIX<sup>e</sup>, qui sont des écoles de formation d'instituteurs (enseignants du primaire), et qui n'existent plus aujourd'hui sous cette forme ;
- les [écoles normales supérieures](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89cole_normale_sup%C3%A9rieure), destinées à former des enseignants pour l'université (enseignement supérieur).

Le terme a une histoire commune avec d'autres langues : [Normalschule](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalschule) en Autriche, [Scuola Normale Superiore](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scuola_normale_superiore) en Italie, [normal schools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_school) dans plusieurs pays anglophones, etc.

Le mot anglais *normalized* a la même étymologie, mais “*normal school*” est une expression consacrée qui n'a pas le sens que “*normalized school*” pourrait avoir (une “*normal school*” est plutôt *normative* que *normalized*).

Comment: > vieux con ou archicube ?